# Unable to convert Reports from sfdx sources to metadatas - force:source:convert / force:source:deploy

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-reports, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

For some time now, we have issues to deploy items that are defined in folders (Reports, emails, documents...)

Problem: Unable to convert Reports from sources to metadata

Command: `MD_API_TEMP_FOLDER=./tmp sfdx force:source:convert -x manifest/package.xml`

Package.xml content (truncated)

```
  <types>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Contratsclients</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Contratsclients/Date_dbut_contrat_Appli_Mois_M_et_M1_ilK</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Contratsclients/Echance_Contrat_Cadre_cek</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Contratsclients/Nouveau_rapport_FM1</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Divers</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Divers/Interco_France_M4x</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Divers/Suivi_Montant_garantie_Hhr</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Facture</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Facture/clients_en_irrgularit_DsY</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Soustraitants</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Soustraitants/Contrat_ST_Fin_ce_moisci_dUJ</members>
    <members>ADMINISTRATIFAssistantesAdmin/Soustraitants/Contrat_ST_Fin_mois_prochain_CnH</members>
    <members>COMMERCIALBusinessDevelopper</members>
    <members>COMMERCIALBusinessDevelopper/Prvisionnel</members>
    <members>COMMERCIALBusinessDevelopper/Prvisionnel/CAannuel</members>
    <members>COMMERCIALBusinessDevelopper/Prvisionnel/Marge_annuelle_GHj</members>
    <members>COMMERCIALBusinessDevelopper/Prvisionnel/TJM_Affectation_actives_cnN</members>
    <name>Report</name>
  </types>
```

- Existing sfdx sources:

[image]

- Result in MD_API_TEMP_DIR: **contain only root folders, no report**

[image]

- When trying to use force:source:deploy

[image]

- Installation:

  - Package.xml & sfdx-project are using apiVersion v53.0
  - plugins

```
sfdx-cli/7.117.0 win32-x64 node-v15.9.0
@salesforce/sfdx-scanner 2.5.1
sfdmu 4.4.5
sfdx-essentials 2.10.0
sfdx-git-delta 4.9.0
sfdx-hardis 2.52.0
sfpowerkit 3.2.3
shane-sfdx-plugins 4.43.0
├─ @mshanemc/plugin-streaming 1.1.7
└─ @mshanemc/sfdx-sosl 1.1.0
texei-sfdx-plugin 1.11.0
```

Comment: definitely not having a solution on this one, but I think we have a bug here. When retrieving with the full path (parentfolder/subfolder/report), i get returned nothing. Retrieving parentfolder/subfolder returns this beauty: 'sfdx-src\main\default\emailservices\Test_Report_Folder-meta.xml-meta.xml' and retrieving subfolder/report is also just empty. Have you searched for existing sfdx issues / created one?

Comment: addition to my comment, I tried to retrieve the structure to reproduce your issue, but as this was not possible i had my doubts that subfolders are working as expected in the metadata :D

Comment: @Hyperzwerg it seems it's a known bug, I'll wait for a new sdx-cli version to close this question :) https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1165